# Udp reads empty bytes after first time - mono android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

On my `Xamarin.Android` app I'm sending udp broadcast message to find my servers on the local LAN.
My servers then return the MachineName they run on which I display in a ListView on my app in the form of

`<MachineName> - <Ip address>`

This all works well on the first time, however from the second time on all it reads is empty bytes. 
The number of bytes it reads is correct but they are all zero.

Here is the code:

```
private static void ListenForBroadcastResponses()
{
    udp.BeginReceive(OnBroadcastResponse, new object());
}

private static void OnBroadcastResponse(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    // Recieve the message
    IPEndPoint ip = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, port);
    byte[] bytes = udp.EndReceive(ar, ref ip);
    // Decode it
    string message = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes);
    // If message is the awaited message from client or from the awaited port
    if (ip.Port == port) //|| message == BRDCAST_ANSWER)
    {
        // Raise server found event
        var handler = ServerFound;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(null, new ServerEventArgs
            {
                Server = new Server(message, ip.Address)
            });
    }

    // Start listening again
    ListenForBroadcastResponses();
}
```

Debug screenshots:

First time full bytes are recieved:
[image: First time]

Second time and on bytes are empty:
[image: Second time and on]

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I figured it out. It seems to be a bug caused by multiple threads trying to listen simultaneously (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26280774/asynchronous-udp-receiving-null-bytes?noredirect=1#comment46368344_26280774) post) to replies so I'll post my solution:

1. I've added a `RecieveTimeout` of `X` seconds to the `UdpClient`.
2. Upon timeout, I execute an `EndRecieve` and `Close` method calls.
3. This will trigger the callback passed in `BeginRecieve` to execute so I've added a check to the callback method if the client is still open
   `if (udp.Client != null) ...`

It fixed things for me, so hopefully it will help others